# how to merge columns in a jsp file

Tags: jsp

I'm creating a list in a jsp file from a db table, the problem is  that some rows are practically the same information, and it only changes in 2 columns,

something like this

```
#  || Process|| TimeShed || Next Time || Server || is Active || Emails || Description

1  || process 1 || Everyday || NA || Server1 || Yes || from: || mail1@mail.com
2  || process 1 || Everyday || NA || Server1 || Yes || To: || mail2@mail.com
3  || process 1 || Everyday || NA || Server1 || Yes || Cc: || mail3@mail.com
4  || process 1 || Everyday || NA || Server1 || Yes || BCc: || mail4@mail.com
```

and my question is, how can I merge the columns to show something like this:

```
#  || Process|| TimeShed || Next Time || Server || is Active || Emails || Description

                                                      from: || mail1@mail.com
1 || process 1 || Everyday || NA || Server1 || Yes ||   To: || mail2@mail.com
                                                        Cc: || mail3@mail.com
                                                       BCc: || mail4@mail.com
```

here is the code from my jsp

```
                    <tr class="odd">
                    <th style="width: 25px;" class="border" align="center">#</th>
                    <th style="width: 200px;" class="border">Process</th>
                    <th style="width: 328px;" class="border">Time Schedule</th>
                    <th style="width: 100px;" class="border">Next time running</th>
                    <th style="width: 50px;" class="border">Server</th>
                    <th style="width: 70px;" class="border">On Off</th>
                    <th style="width: 50px;" class="border">Emails</th>
                    <th style="width: 50px;" class="border">Description</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <c:forEach items="${JobList}" var="job" varStatus="index" >
                            <td align="center">${index.count}</td>
                            <td align="center">${job.process}</td>
                            <td align="center">${job.schedTime}</td>
                            <td align="center">
                            <c:if test="${job.nextTimeRun eq null}">NA</c:if>
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">${job.lookName}</td>
                            <td>    
                                <input type="checkbox" name="isActive" id="isActive" value="true" onclick="updateJobStatus();"
                                <c:if test="${job.isActive eq Constants.YES}">checked='checked'</c:if> />
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <c:if test="${job.mailOrder == '1'}">From</c:if>
                                <c:if test="${job.mailOrder == '2'}">To:</c:if>
                                <c:if test="${job.mailOrder == '3'}">Cc:</c:if>
                                <c:if test="${job.mailOrder == '4'}">BCc:</c:if>
                            </td>           
                            <td align="center">${job.description}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                <tr><td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td></tr>
            </tbody>
```

I apologize I don't have enough rep to post images, so I tried my best to show somehow the doubt I have of how can I make my jsp show what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `<td colspan='5'></td>` rather than `<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>` If that doesn't answer the question, then I don't get the question. It sounds like you want to merge many cells as one sometimes. That's how you do it. Now you just need to figure out the logic for when to do it and when not to.

So `<td colspan='5'></td>` is 5 tds displayed as one. Or in other words, one td that spans what would be 5 tds in another row.

When you do that, you'll probably want to use `align='right'` or `align='left'` rather than `align='center'` for that one.

So for example:

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td colspan='3' align='right'>1-3</td>
   <td>4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

This will give:

```
1  2  3  4
    1-3  4
```